# Convert from Object to Float not working c++

Tags: c++, class, object

I'm trying to convert a object to a float, but it doesn't seems to work the way I want.

```
int main()
{
  Fraction A(20,6);
  float E;  
  E = A;
  cout << E << endl;
}
```

I already did a type convert operator inside the class

```
operator float () const     
    {           
        return static_cast<float>(num/den);  //Being num and den private members, 20 and 6 in this case. 
    }
```

When I run the program, the result is 3 (with no decimal places).
Any help?

Comment: You haven't provided the types for num and dem, but I bet they're integral. Cast one of them before you divide and see what you get.

Comment: num/den is an integer division.

Comment: Maybe: `return float(num)/den` (but you do not provide enough information)

Comment: `20/6 == 3` I think you will find, integer division

Comment: Delete the parens around (num/den)!

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your code, but based on the behavior you're observing, is it possible that `num` and `den` are defined as `int` data types? If so, `num/den` is being treated as integer division, and therefore resulting in the result being truncated.